# Python threading classes

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface

I am rookie to Python threading and am looking for guidance on how to implement mulithreading on an application with two classes, GUI and weblogic that need need to run in parallel.

The GUI class is all about user interaction and will have code like "if you click here run this weblogic method."  The GUI must be in its own thread because  the weblogic method can be slow and so waiting for it to complete will cause the GUI to seem unresponsive.  The good news is that GUI code has no ability to modify any data inside the weblogic thread and so locking is not an issue. (The GUI just calls a weblogic method with the appropriate variables and then processes the resulting output.)

The web logic class includes multiple methods and constructors and some of the methods can be time consuming to run. The class also includes constructors that are vital to all the methods in the class.  (Think userid, password, API access url and the like)

So what I am looking to implement is a way to instantiate the two threads in parallel. Hence, the GUI would run in its own thread and issue commands to the weblogic thread which would respond accordingly.

I started looking at the Threading module and while I have gotten it to work for simplistic functions, I have not been successful in running an entire class inside a thread. Since I am new to all of this, I am looking for guidance on the right strategy. Should I even be using Threading? Is there better approach?

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

GUI Code:

```
class GUI():
    def createGUI(self):
        # create GUI layout here

    def button1(self):
        # if clicked
        outputtodisplay = weblogic.filelist()
        # display outputtodisplay

    def button2(self)
        # if clicked assume that we have a file selector box which provides a filename
        weblogic.uploadfile(filename)
        # show an upload success indicator
```

Weblogic:

```
class weblogic():
    def __init__(self, count, instance):
        # run some stuff to setup
        self.uid = xxx
        self.pwd = yyy
        self.url = zzz

    def listfiles():
        # get file list using uid, pwd, url
        return output

    def uploadfile(self,filename):
        # upload file using uid, pwd, url
        return success/failure
```

Comment: What user-interface are you using?

Comment: For starters I would look into multiprocessing instead because you can only have 1 python thread run at any given time. So you will get better performance with multiprocessing as it creates processes.

Comment: Hi, I will be using wxPython.

Comment: You named a class weblogic, and you have url's in your notes. I don't want to make any assumptions, but is this going to be a web application, or is this going to be a standalone application?

Comment: It will be a local application.  I randomly chose the weblogic class name for this pseudo code.  Sorry if it is confusing.  That class is the logic that I will use to query/upload/download from a remote storage target over the Internet.  However, all of the core app logic will run locally.

Comment: I would test out Fredrik's comment. You can exchange variables in multiprocessing using Queues and Pipes. Documentation for multiprocessing is available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Unfortunately I've never used it myself (Web applications you could just make the webLogic part into a service that gets called by the GUI), so I can't be of more help.